# Нow to define a constant managed record with an overridden assignment method

Tags: delphi, assembly, record

I'm writing a program for mathematical research. Assembly language is used for speed. Data is represented as managed records with operator overloads. Some data is represented by constants.

```
program TestMR;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMR = record
  public
    Data: array[0..3] of Double;
    class operator Implicit(const Src: Int64): TMR; overload;
    //class operator Assign(var Dest: TMR; const [ref] Src: TMR);
  end;

{ TMR }
{
class operator TMR.Assign(var Dest: TMR; const [ref] Src: TMR);
asm
  vmovdqu ymm0, dqword ptr [rdx]
  vmovdqu dqword ptr [rcx], ymm0
end;
}
class operator TMR.Implicit(const Src: Int64): TMR;
asm
  vcvtsi2sd xmm1, xmm1, rdx
  vpbroadcastq ymm0, xmm1
  vmovdqu yword ptr [rcx], ymm0
  ret
end;

const
  cD: TMR = (Data:(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0));

var
  vD: TMR;

begin
  vD := 4;
  vD := cD;
end.
```

The standard assignment method is represented by the compiler as ...

```
000000000042A10F 488D3D8A4E0100   lea rdi,[rel $00014e8a]
000000000042A116 488D7520         lea rsi,[rbp+$20]
000000000042A11A 48A5             movsq
000000000042A11C 48A5             movsq
000000000042A11E 48A5             movsq
000000000042A120 48A5             movsq
```

It's slow. If I overload an assignment method, the compiler write an error **E2635 Declaring a managed record constant in const section is not allowed.** Нow to define a constant managed record with an overridden assignment method?
Also is there a method to make forced overloaded operators inline?

Comment: Not sure it matters, but which version of Delphi were you using?

Comment: Inlined methods/overloaded operators cannot have asm blocks. And no, inlined methods cannot be forced, it is up to the compiler to decide.

Comment: Your record doesn't contain any compiler-managed data types, so it shouldn't be a *managed* record to begin with. I'd be worried that just adding operators to it is making it managed. But, if you change your operators into standalone functions, you should be able to define constants of your *unmanaged* record type.

Comment: @DavidDyck Custom Managed Records Coming to Delphi 10.4. Now I use Delphi 11.1

Comment: @RemyLebeau The error appears only after overriding the Assign method.

Comment: You don't need to override `Assign()` in an *unmanaged* record. The standard `:=` operator will suffice to copy *unmanaged* data, or you can use `CopyMemory()`/`Move()` instead. Your array consists of *unmanaged* data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, as I understand the intention to introduce the Assign was just because the standard := operator seems to do a bad job.

Comment: @UweRaabe for records containing *managed* data types, perhaps. Not for records containing *unmanaged* data types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Remy Lebeau for the tip about managed and unmanaged data. I may have found a solution...

```
program TestMR;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMR = record
  public
    Data: array[0..3] of Double;
    class operator Implicit(const Src: Int64): TMR; overload;
    class operator Implicit(const [ref] Src: TMR): String; overload; inline;
    class operator Add(const [ref] O1: TMR; const [ref] O2: TMR): TMR; overload;
    class operator Assign(var Dest: TMR; const [ref] Src: TMR);
  end;

{ TMR }

class operator TMR.Add(const [ref] O1: TMR; const [ref] O2: TMR): TMR;
asm
  vmovdqu ymm0, yword ptr [rdx]
  vaddpd ymm0, ymm0, yword ptr [r8]
  vmovdqu yword ptr [rcx], ymm0
  vzeroupper
  ret
end;

class operator TMR.Assign(var Dest: TMR; const [ref] Src: TMR);
asm
  vmovdqu ymm0, yword ptr [rdx]
  vmovdqu yword ptr [rcx], ymm0
  vzeroupper
  ret
end;

class operator TMR.Implicit(const [ref] Src: TMR): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  for var i: Integer := 0 to 3 do Result := Result + FloatToStr(Src.Data[i]) + '   ';
end;

class operator TMR.Implicit(const Src: Int64): TMR;
asm
  vcvtsi2sd xmm1, xmm1, rdx
  vpbroadcastq ymm0, xmm1
  vmovdqu yword ptr [rcx], ymm0
  vzeroupper
  ret
end;

var
  vD: TMR;

const
  cA: array[0..3] of Double = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

begin
  vD := TMR(cA);
  vD := TMR(cA) + vD;
  WriteLn(String(vD));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Now it would be nice to solve the problem of the possibility of making these functions inline. Сall and ret take approximately 6 ticks on Haswell.

Comment: FYI `vbroadcastpd` would be a more appropriate 64-bit broadcast for FP data.  I don't know if any AVX2 CPUs have extra bypass latency for SIMD-integer <-> FP for using an integer shuffle on the result of an FP instruction (I think Intel CPUs probably won't), but there's no advantage in mismatching.  Also, you might want to `vcvtsi2sd xmm1, xmm7, rdx` to avoid a false dependency, using some hopefully-cold reg as the merge target instead of the same register you're updating in the previous loop iteration.

Comment: Also, if you're going to manually vectorize with SIMD, it would probably be easier to use a language like C++ if you know it; it has intrinsics for this (`#include <immintrin.h>`).  It could inline your functions to avoid extra store/reload latency every time you use a vector (which may dominate the `call`/`ret` front-end bottleneck), and also avoid the overhead of `vzeroupper` for every operation.  (You might be able to omit that if the compiler happens not to emit legacy-SSE instructions between your functions, at least in some places.)

Comment: But if you can't omit `vzeroupper`, it costs 4 uops for the front-end on Intel.  It might be faster to just do your FP operations in two XMM halves, not dirtying a YMM upper.  (Still use the `v` version so you can use an unaligned memory source operand for `vaddpd`.)

Comment: Or write more of your loop by hand in asm, if you insist on using a language without SIMD support.  C++ isn't the only choice, there's also Rust (at least with nightly builds, IDK if their SIMD intrinsics are stable yet) and C# with decent intrinsics, as well as C and C++.  Or with code that can auto-vectorize, good compilers can auto-vectorize languages like Fortan, as well as some simple C code.  (GCC and clang can even vectorize outside of loops, e.g. a plain C version of your `implicit` function compiles to about your hand-written asm: https://godbolt.org/z/zhzrKjfc8)

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if doing this made any real difference to runs times. You are going to be pace blocked by all the other problems of the Delphi compiler.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tips on optimizing the speed of the asm code. `vpbroadcastq` and `vbroadcastsd` are executed in the same number of cycles, but really, it is better to use each in the context of the data type. `vzeroupper` can be omitted, although this is considered a classic in AVX programming.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know C++ very well, so it took some time to write the code.The implementation of the operators is written in an external .asm file. I took this trick from Creel [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTNG-Ukvc3c&t=919s).

```cpp
// TestTMR.cpp

#include <iostream>
struct TMR {
    double Data[4];
    inline TMR& operator = (const long long Src);
    inline TMR& operator = (const TMR& Src);
    friend inline TMR& operator + (const TMR& O1, const TMR& O2);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const TMR& Src);
 };

TMR vD;

TMR const cA = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const TMR& Src)
{
    return out << Src.Data[0] << "  " << Src.Data[1] << "  " << Src.Data[2] << "  " << Src.Data[3];
};

int main()
{
    vD = 4;
    vD = cA;
    vD = cA + vD;
   std::cout << vD << std::endl;
}
```

```
;TestTMRasm.asm
.code

; inline TMR& operator = (const long long Src)
??4TMR@@QEAAAEAU0@_J@Z proc
    vcvtsi2sd xmm1, xmm7, rdx
    vbroadcastsd ymm0, xmm1
    vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rcx], ymm0
    ret
??4TMR@@QEAAAEAU0@_J@Z endp

; inline TMR& operator = (const TMR& Src);
??4TMR@@QEAAAEAU0@AEBU0@@Z proc
    vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdx]
    vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rcx], ymm0
    ret
??4TMR@@QEAAAEAU0@AEBU0@@Z endp

; inline TMR& operator + (const TMR& O1, const TMR& O2)
??H@YAAEAUTMR@@AEBU0@0@Z proc
    sub rsp, 20h
    vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [rcx]
    vmovdqu ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdx]
    vaddpd ymm0, ymm1, ymm2
    vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsp], ymm0
    lea rax, qword ptr [rsp]
    add rsp, 20h
    ret
??H@YAAEAUTMR@@AEBU0@0@Z endp

end
```

However, the C++ compiler, like Delphi, does not make them inline (see the disassembled code). Maybe I didn't set the compilation options correctly. If anyone achieves a positive result, please let me know. C++ proved to be better than Delphi in that there is no need to implement type conversion operators before assignment, as well as the ability to return a reference to the result.
Native support for constants is also good, although Delphi will simply pass the reference to `cA` to the statement when calling `TMR(cA)`.

```
    23:     vD = 4;
00007FF7BAC710F4 BA 04 00 00 00       mov         edx,4  
00007FF7BAC710F9 48 8D 0D 28 45 00 00 lea         rcx,[vD (07FF7BAC75628h)]  
00007FF7BAC71100 E8 7B 07 00 00       call        TMR::operator= (07FF7BAC71880h)  
    24:     vD = cA;
00007FF7BAC71105 48 8D 15 C4 21 00 00 lea         rdx,[cA (07FF7BAC732D0h)]  
00007FF7BAC7110C 48 8D 0D 15 45 00 00 lea         rcx,[vD (07FF7BAC75628h)]  
00007FF7BAC71113 E8 77 07 00 00       call        TMR::operator= (07FF7BAC7188Fh)  
    25:     vD = cA + vD;
00007FF7BAC71118 48 8D 15 09 45 00 00 lea         rdx,[vD (07FF7BAC75628h)]  
00007FF7BAC7111F 48 8D 0D AA 21 00 00 lea         rcx,[cA (07FF7BAC732D0h)]  
00007FF7BAC71126 E8 6D 07 00 00       call        operator+ (07FF7BAC71898h)  
00007FF7BAC7112B 48 8B D0             mov         rdx,rax  
00007FF7BAC7112E 48 8D 0D F3 44 00 00 lea         rcx,[vD (07FF7BAC75628h)]  
00007FF7BAC71135 E8 55 07 00 00       call        TMR::operator= (07FF7BAC7188Fh)
```

Comment: C++ and assembly are different languages. There's no plausible way for a C++ compiler to inline a function that you only define in a hand-written `.asm` file.  This is why I said you should use **intriniscs** like `__m256d v = __m256_load_pd(vD.Data)` which compilers can optimize.

Comment: It's also buggy; your `operator +`  stores to `[rsp]` (a local in its own stack frame) and then returns a pointer to it. Once back in the caller, it's below the current RSP, so not safe from signal handlers, and will be stepped on by any future function call. It's exactly like `int *foo(){int x=1; return &x;}` which is undefined behaviour in C and C++ because it would naturally compile to asm like that.  (`int &` references are mostly just syntactic sugar over pointers.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7odcxo3E9 shows a simple `TMR add(TMR &a, TMR &b)` with intrinsics.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).